# How to 301 redirect in htaccess from old url with parameters to new?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect from old url to new url 
Like this

Old:

```
uae/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product-details.php?product=$3&id=$2&brand=$1
```

to

New:

```
RewriteRule ^uae/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product-details.php?product=$2&brand=$1
```

Comment: You're showing 2 rules but you should show old and new URLs

Comment: Old url
http://www.adawliahuae.com/uae/brand/alto-professional/loudspeakers/alto-professional-active-loudspeaker-tsl-115 and new is http://www.adawliahuae.com/uae/alto-professional-active-loudspeaker-tsl-115

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(uae)/.+/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```